# 500 error when sending email via AJAX (Laravel 5.4)

Tags: php, ajax, email, laravel-5

I'm trying to have a form send emails in a Laravel project. However, I keep receiving 500 error. I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09rshFmGwc0&t=499s) tutorial.

This is the route:

```
    Route::post('contact', 'PagesController@contact');
```

This is the controller:

```
public function contact(Request $request) {

    $this->validate($request, [
        'email'=>'required|email',
        'fullname'=>'max:50'
        ]);

    $data = array(
        'email' => $request->email,
        'fullname' => $request->fullname,
        );

    Mail::send('emails.contact', $data, function($message) use ($data){
        $message->from($data['email']);
        $message->to('moghrabi@gmail.com');

    });
}
```

This is the view that contains the HTML form with the CSRF as noted by previous questions.

```
<form onsubmit="return false" method="post" id="contact_form" name="contact-form">

    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_field() }}">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fullname" id="fullname" required>
    <input class="form-control" aria-describedby='sizing-addon1' placeholder="Email Address" required name="email" id="email">
    <button id="contact_btn" data-loading-text="Sending" >Send Your Message</button>

</form>
```

This is the AJAX code:

```
$('#contact_form').submit(function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
            }).validate({ 

          rules: {
            fullname: {
              required: true,

            },
            email: {
              required: true,
              email: true
            },
         },
          submitHandler: function (form) {

            var btn = $('#contact_btn');
            btn.button('loading');
            setTimeout(function() {
              btn.button('reset');
            }, 8000);

            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: "{{url('contact')}}",

              dataType: 'json',
              async: true,
              data: {

                fullname: $('#fullname').val(),
                email: $('#email').val(),

          },

              success: function (json) {
                $('#contact').hide();
                $('#output').html(
                  '<p>We have received your message!</p>'
                  ).show();
              }
            });
               return false; 
        } 
   });
```

in Chrome dev tools:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)

Comment: last section of log is useless. `#1` is what you want to check

Comment: Check your http server error log.

Comment: `$data['subject']` __not__ exists.

Comment: I updated server logs.

Comment: improved question formatting

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in this line:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_field() }}">
```

You should use `csrf_token()` not `csrf_field()` because the last one generate the csrf input field and the first one only token.
Also add token to ajax request in your data:

```
data: {
...
'_token':$('[name="_token"]').val(),
...
}
```

or in ajax header before calling ajax function:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('[name="_token"]').val()
      }
    });
```